# equivalent identifiers in C++

Tags: java, c++

I am new to programming and I have a simple doubt.

I was wondering if there is an equivalent identifier like public private etc in C++ like present in java. for ex I know

In Java

```
*public String small(){
return "hello";
}*
```

In C++

```
*string small(){
return "hello";
}*
```

Comment: Within a C++ `class` you can have `private:` or `protected:` or `public:` member (data or functions). But you are going nowhere by learning C++ this way. Take many hours to read, study a good C++ programming book (C++ is a difficult language to learn) and practice a lot. Don't forget to ask for all warnings by your C++ compiler, and debugging info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -g` on Linux). Learn how to use the debugger (`gdb` on Linux). You'll need it!

Answer (score 5):

In C++ you don't apply access specifiers to individual declarations like in Java.  You set them up in sections within a class, and all the members up to the next access specifier have that access level.

```
class MyClass {
public:
    std::string small() const { return "hello"; }
    int also_public();
private:
    void another_func();
};
```

Answer (score 4):

There is, but limited to class scope. When referring to members, they define whole sections, rather being applied individually to each member:

```
class Foo : public Bar // public inheritance. Can be private. Or even protected!
{
 public:.
  int a; // public
  double b; // still public
 private:
  double x; // private
 public:
  double y; // public again:
 protected:
  // some protected stuff
};
```

access specifiers do not apply to classes (and there is no concept of modules in C++). A class can only be private/protected if it is nested within another class.

Answer (score 4):

In C++ there are public/private/protected "sections":

```
class A
{
private:
    string a;
    void M1();

protected:
    string b;
    void M2();

public:
    string c;
    void M3();
};
```

Answer (score 3):

C++ has accessibility modifiers, but unlike Java you don't have to repeat them on every single member:

```
class C
{
    int a; // private, since class members are private by default
public:
    int b; // public, since it's in a block of public members
    int c; // also public
private:
    int d; // private again
protected:
    int e; // protected
};

struct S
{
    int a; // public, since struct implicitly gives a block of public members
public:
    int b; // public, since it's in a block of public members
    int c; // also public
private:
    int d; // private again
protected:
    int e; // protected
};
```

Incidentally, the blocks created by accessibility labels not only control access, but also affect memory layout.

This class is *standard-layout* and *POD*:

```
struct S
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};
```

so is this:

```
struct S
{
private:
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};
```

but this is not:

```
struct S
{
    int a;
    int b;
private:
    int c;
};
```

And this one is in C++11, but not in C++03:

```
struct S
{
    int a;
    int b;
public:
    int c;
};
```

Comment: @juan: Yeah I noticed that.  I wonder if they were manually removed or triggered an anti-spree script.

Answer (score 0):

in C++

```
const char *small() {
    return "hello";
}
```

or

```
std::string small() {
    return "hello";
}
```

depending on if you want a character array or a string object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use public, private and protected inside a c++ class.

For example

```
Class A {
public:
 int x;
 int getX() { return x; }

private:
 int y;
};
```

Here x and getX function are public. and y is private.

Comment: missing colon after `public: int getX() `

Comment: and missing return type, and extra unneeded semicolon

Comment: Sorry about the minor edit, but it wouldn't let me change my vote until an edit happened, and your ninja edit wasn't counting.